# Using mathematical induction to prove a divisibility

Tags: induction, divisibility

I am having trouble to prove that if $a\mid b_1, a\mid b_2, \dots, a\mid b_n$, then $a \mid (b_1 + b_2 + \cdots + b_n)$.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: You do **not** need mathematical induction; you just need the definition of $a\mid b$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:  We have had a succession of problems asking for an inductive proof when that is possible but there is an easier direct proof.  I have made that comment on two others.  Maybe it is that time of the school year.  I assume here one is supposed to induct on $n$

Comment: @RossMillikan: Ugh. I hate problems that force students to use a particular approach: they’re bad pædagogy. But yes, induction on $n$ is certainly feasible and probably what’s intended.

Comment: How to you propose to *rigorously* prove it without using induction (or some equivalent)?  Of course we need more context to know if such rigor is expected.

Comment: @Ross See above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By hypothesis, $b_1 = a \times c_1$, $b_2 = a \times c_2$, $\dots$, $b_n = a \times c_n$. Then $b_1 + b_2 + \dots + b_n = a \times c_1 + a \times c_2 + \dots + a \times c_n = a(c_1 + c_2 + \dots + c_n)$. Hence $a$ divides the sum $b_1 + b_2 + \dots + b_n$. Hope this helps.

Comment: Using stars for multiplication without dollar signs to invoke MathJax is what causes the italics in your answer.  Please use MathJax and \cdot to make a dot for multiplication.  You also are not consistent in using underscore for subscripts.  If you put the dollar signs, the underscore will give nice subscripts, so b_n enclosed in dollar signs gives $b_n$